# Gaussian elimination on matrix.. Is there a better way to extract the solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So, I used Gaussian elimination on this matrix

$$\left( \begin{array}{c} -1 & 3 & 5 & 13 \\ 3 & -2 & 2 & 16 \end{array}\right)$$

to turn it to this:

$$\left( \begin{array}{c} -1 & 3 & 5 & 13 \\ 0 & 7 & 17 & 55 \end{array} \right)$$

I don't think this could be eliminated any further.

Which gives me these two equations:

$$-1a + 3b + 5c = 13$$

$$          7b + 17c = 55$$

Is there another method after this to simplify finding what the variables are, or is the only way to guess and check?

Thank you.

Comment: Your reduction has an error. What is $3 R1 + R2 \rightarrow R2$?

Comment: Divide the second row by $7$. Multiply $-R1 \rightarrow R1$. Now, use second row to get rid of the second entry in $R1$. Clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still do some reductions based on my comments and get this down to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \dfrac{16}{7} & \dfrac{74}{7} \\ 0 & 1 & \dfrac{17}{7} & \dfrac{55}{7} \end{bmatrix}$$

**Update**

From this RREF, we have:

- $b = \dfrac{55}{7} - \dfrac{17}{7}c$
- $a = \dfrac{74}{7} - \dfrac{16}{7}c$

This gives us a "free variable", $c$, which you are free to choose values for.

Comment: Ah.. back substitution. Forgot about that. Thanks you!

Comment: Now my next question. After reducing it fully, there are still 3 variables to figure out. I know what the answers are from guessing and checking, but is there another method after this or is trial and error the only way?

Comment: No guessing required, please see my update. You can choose ANY $c$ you like. Pick various values for $c$, calculate $a$ and $b$ and make sure it solves the original system. Regards

Comment: Nicely done! +1

Comment: @amWhy: As always, thank you kindly for the support!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be widely unknown that from
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \dfrac{16}{7} & \dfrac{74}{7} \\ 0 & 1 & \dfrac{17}{7} & \dfrac{55}{7} \end{bmatrix}$$
you don't need any backward substitution.  Just write
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \dfrac{16}{7} & \dfrac{74}{7} \\ 0 & 1 & \dfrac{17}{7} & \dfrac{55}{7}\\
0&0&-1&0
 \end{bmatrix}$$
from which we conclude -- sharp eyes provided -- the solutions
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{74}{7} \\ \dfrac{55}{7}\\ 0
 \end{bmatrix}
+\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{16}{7} \\ \dfrac{17}{7} & \\ -1
 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Do you how and why this works?